# form.io how to trigger custom validation on blur?

Tags: javascript, formio

In form.io form builder i am adding custom validation but the default is to trigger the validation on change i want to set it to on blur.

I have tried the following code on the custom validation tab:

```
let field = document.querySelector('input[name="data[nametest]"]');
field.addEventListener("blur", checkValidation);




function checkValidation() { 
console.log('checking...');
          valid = (input.length > 5) ? true : 'Test name must be at least 5 characters long' ;
        }
```

the code is running on blur but it is not showing the error the valid global variable is set to the correct error message its just not showing on the form also i notice that the more characters on the textfield the more the event gets trigger on blur, I would be gratefull for any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the Form Builder view, validity checks are disabled.  You may test simple validations in the component settings modal:

[image]

Now, in case you want to trigger an action on blur, you must consider that custom validation is not persistent and is calculated on every evaluation, meaning that whatever you do with it after it has been evaluated will not affect the component itself.  You will need to attach the event directly into the component instance.

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. **Using a Hidden Component**

Create a hidden component in your form and set it to not persistent (you don't want to store a value, just run) and define a custom default script to run at form rendered.

```js
const { root } = instance;
const comp = root ? root.getComponent('key') : null;

if (comp) {
  // remove any listener to avoid duplicates
  comp.off('blur');
  // define the on blur listener
  comp.on('blur', () => {
    console.log('blur');
  });
}
```

2. **On Form Ready**

```js
Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), form).then((formio) => {
  const component = formio.getComponent('key');

  if (component) {
    component.on('focus', () => {
        console.log('focus');
    });
    component.on('blur', () => {
        console.log('blur');
    });
  }
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/airarrazaval/ongcuwt2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know since which version this option exists, but at least with version 4.13 the form builder has a specific property to address your concern - `Validate On`:

[image: Choose Blur as your validation trigger]

This should work perfectly fine with your custom validation code, as well.